# How should i go about developing chrome extension like this

Tags: google-chrome-extension

A extension that takes a photo and make it into webcam stream. So if i have website requesting access to webcam then this would show up as possible webcam to share with.

I know javascript and a bit of chrome extension api. But i don't know how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Chrome extension API that will allow you to create a webcam that will show up in other applications.

Comment: There is screen share, would it be possible to make use of that somehow.